# Fused Electrons Spin

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin, elementary-particles

If it was possible to make two electrons fuse, would it also be possible to increase the magnitude of that object's spin since it is not an elementary particle?

Comment: Since making electrons fuse is not consistent with current physics, this will likely be closed.

Comment: Are you asking about [Cooper pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_pair)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to fuse two electrons. In the spirit of your question, the question of adding angular momentum is not as simple as adding the magnitudes. [This link](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node31.html) can better describe the process involved.